# "amount must be a Numeric" Rails Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the `active_shipping` gem on my rails app and am getting a very strange error reading:

```
amount must be a Numeric
```

The error is being called on my shipping method:

```
def shipping
    @user = current_user
    @products = current_order.order_items.all
    @order = current_order

    packages =  []
    @products.each do |thing|
      packages << ActiveShipping::Package.new( thing.product.weight * 16,  <<<<<<<<<<ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE
      [thing.product.box_length, thing.product.box_width, thing.product.box_depth],
      units: :imperial)
    end ## each do

    origin = ActiveShipping::Location.new( country: 'US', state: 'CO', city: 'Sedalia', zip: '80135')

    if @user.country == 'US'
      destination = ActiveShipping::Location.new( country: @user.country, state: @user.state, city: @user.city, zip: @user.zip)
    else
      destination = ActiveShipping::Location.new( country: @user.country, province: @user.state, city: @user.city, postal_code: @user.zip)
    end # if/else for country

    ups = ActiveShipping::UPS.new(login: 'lizbayardelle', password: 'UPSpassw0rd', key: '3D287D7B39D0D398')
    ups_response = ups.find_rates(origin, destination, packages)
    @ups_rates = ups_response.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect {|rate| [rate.service_name, rate.price]}

    usps = ActiveShipping::USPS.new(login: '380LINCH6422')
    usps_response = usps.find_rates(origin, destination, packages)
    @usps_rates = usps_response.rates.sort_by(&:price).collect {|rate| [rate.service_name, rate.price]}
  end
```

The value for the product weight is in the `seeds.rb` file:

```
Product.delete_all
Product.create! id: 1, name: "Rule #23 Tee Shirt (Small)", weight: 1, box_width: 6, box_length: 9, box_depth: 2, price: 32.00, short_description: "Size Small. Spread the word. These tee shirts not only have the Manly Art crest, but they also have a man rule on the back to remind any passers-by that may have forgotten.", active: true
Product.create! id: 2, name: "Rule #23 Tee Shirt (Medium)", weight: 1, box_width: 6, box_length: 9, box_depth: 2, price: 32.00, short_description: "Size Medium. Spread the word. These tee shirts not only have the Manly Art crest, but they also have a man rule on the back to remind any passers-by that may have forgotten.", active: true
Product.create! id: 3, name: "Rule #23 Tee Shirt (Large)", weight: 1, box_width: 6, box_length: 9, box_depth: 2, price: 32.00, short_description: "Size Large. Spread the word. These tee shirts not only have the Manly Art crest, but they also have a man rule on the back to remind any passers-by that may have forgotten.", active: true
Product.create! id: 4, name: "Rule #23 Tee Shirt (XL)", weight: 1, box_width: 12, box_length: 14, box_depth: 3, price: 32.00, short_description: "Size XL. Spread the word. These tee shirts not only have the Manly Art crest, but they also have a man rule on the back to remind any passers-by that may have forgotten.", active: true
Product.create! id: 5, name: "Grill Glove", weight: 1, box_width: 6, box_length: 9, box_depth: 2, price: 32.00, short_description: "Protect your manly mitts from the fiery dangers of the grill.", active: true
Product.create! id: 6, name: "BBQ Apron", weight: 1, box_width: 6, box_length: 9, box_depth: 2, price: 32.00, short_description: "Standard grilling apron with three pockets for all your necessary tools.  You get to add the grease marks and stains from the marinade of your choosing.", active: true
```

Can anyone see what's going on here?  Google/Stack Overflow don't seem to have heard of this error, which is worrisome...

Comment: Try inspecting `thing.product.weight`

Comment: @Pavan, `thing.product.weight` is `#<BigDecimal:7fdc204482d0,'0.1E1',9(27)>` (aka `1`).

Comment: Try `(thing.product.weight * 16).to_i`

Comment: @Pavan, same error.

Comment: how do you know that's the line causing the error ?, perhaps is values in the array that's sent as the second parameter, are all of those Numeric values as well ?.

Comment: @fanta, that's the line that's highlighted on my error message...

Comment: @Liz I get that, but it could be that the error is in any of `thing.product.box_length, thing.product.box_width, thing.product.box_depth`, have you tried inspecting the values of those attributes ?. And you're looping through a set of objects, perhaps one of them has something different than a number, you'll need to inspect all of them.

Comment: since I don't really know where the error was, I think it'd be better if you just write what you ended up doing as an answer and accept it yourself so that this question gets resolved and so that people can see how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding .to_i to each thing and it made it work for some reason.